# All styles are insert inline in index.html

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on reactJs app. When running while using dev flag, my stylesheet is inserted in head of index.html page. So styles are adding twice. app.css contains same styles but these should be be injected as inline.

Here is screenshot http://prntscr.com/l6y8h9

Comment: Hey, welcome to SO! It works best here if you state your question or problem very specifically.  You should edit your question to say what you *want* to be happening (not having the inline styles?)

Comment: Yes. Styles should not be added twice and secondly, recommended way is to use link tag to to add stylesheets. So I want to get rid of inline styles.

Answer (score 0):

react-app then it will automaticly bind all your imported css files to your `index.html`. You can clear the one you manually added